# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable in flask with langchain

Tags: python, flask, langchain

#### Description

I am creating a REST API with flask and using langchain and AzureOpenAI, however the llm.stream doesnt seam to work correctly based on my code.

How can I stream AzureOPENAI responses using flask?

#### Example Code

```py
@app.route('/stream2', methods=['GET'])
def stream2():
    try:
        user_query = request.json.get('user_query')
        if not user_query:
            return "No user query provided", 400
        
        callback_handler = StreamHandler()
        callback_manager = CallbackManager([callback_handler])
        llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
            azure_endpoint=AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
            openai_api_version=OPENAI_API_VERSION,
            deployment_name=OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
            openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
            openai_api_type=OPENAI_API_TYPE,
            model_name=OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
            streaming=True,
            model_kwargs={
                "logprobs": None,
                "best_of": None,
                "echo": None
            },
            #callback_manager=callback_manager, 
            temperature=0)
        
        @stream_with_context
        async def generate():
            async for chunk in llm.stream(user_query):
                yield chunk
        
        return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return "An error occurred", 500
```

#### Error Message and Stack Trace (if applicable)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\x\repos\y-chatbot\backend-flask-appservice\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 362, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "c:\Users\x\repos\y-chatbot\backend-flask-appservice\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 325, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "c:\Users\x\repos\y-chatbot\backend-flask-appservice\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 256, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "c:\Users\x\repos\y-chatbot\backend-flask-appservice\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\response.py", line 32, in _iter_encoded        
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

#### System Info

```
langchain==0.1.0
langchain-community==0.0.12
langchain-core==0.1.12
langchainhub==0.1.14
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `async for` on a non-asynchronous method.

Compare this to an example from the Langchain docs:

```
async for chunk in model.astream("hello. tell me something about yourself"):
    chunks.append(chunk)
    print(chunk.content, end="|", flush=True)
```

https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/streaming#llms-and-chat-models

For that reason, I would suggest using:

```
            async for chunk in llm.astream(user_query):
                yield chunk
```

(Warning: solution not tested on my end.)

Comment: TIL that `yield from` doesn't exist for async iterators.